# Detached process does not write to file & rpc call fails with error from connected node

Tags: elixir

I've got an Elixir app that I launch with

```
iex --sname "main" --cookie "abc" --detached -S mix
```

If I start this process without the `detached` option, everything works fine. Amongst other things, the `main` process writes data to a `.csv` file using `File.open` and `IO.write(file_path, data)`. With the `detached` option, nothing is written to the file.

So I thought, I could try connecting to this process from another node that I started with

```
iex --sname "test" --cookie "abc" -S mix
```

Then I do

```
Node.connect(main@localhost)
```

and `Node.list` confirms that I'm connected to the `main` node. The first process contains a functions that returns the file path of the `.csv` file in question. If I call

```
:rpc.call(:main@localhost, Log, :csv_path, [])
```

it returns the error

```
{:badrpc, :EXIT, {:undef, [{Log, :csv_path, [], []}....
```

If I repeat the same thing when I start the `main` node without the `detached` option, this works and returns the correct file path to me.

Which configuration option am I forgetting?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you can't start `iex` in detached mode. `iex` is a shell and it needs input. But detached means there is no input or output. Erlang fails to start iex, and you end up with only bare Erlang running without any indication of what happened.

You can try `:rpc.call(:main@localhost,  Application, :loaded_applications, [])` and you should see that only `stdlib` and `kernel` are running.

If you run `elixir --erl "-detached" --no-halt --sname "main" --cookie "abc" -S mix` it should work fine. Three things to note here:

1. Use `elixir` instead of `iex`.
2. `--detached` is deprecated, so use `--erl "-detached"` instead.
3. Add `--no-halt` because otherwise, elixir immediately exits.